# Create dictionary of dicts from a single list - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Python 3.6.5/3.7.1 on Linux

Struggling to create a dictionary with dictionaries as values.

I want to create a dictionary from a list date & time data (ultimately to create charts with bokeh).

This must have been asked before, but I can't find a set of search terms that returns a result that clarifies matters for me.

nb I'm essentially a hobby coder, & I don't easily think algorithmically like a real programmer.

The data is in a list (max 3200 items):
Each item is a record of the occurrence of an event on a date in a clock period of one hour.

Thus; `['03/01/19 09:00', '03/01/19 09:00', '03/01/19 09:00',]` indicates 3 events between 0900-1000 on 03/01/2019.

Only clock periods with events are recorded, so if no event, no timestamp.

nb date format is `ddmmyy`

Example data:

```
dtl = [
    '06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 11:00', '05/01/19 21:00',
    '05/01/19 17:00', '05/01/19 17:00', '05/01/19 14:00', '03/01/19 21:00',
    '03/01/19 17:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00',
    '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 11:00', '03/01/19 10:00',
    '03/01/19 10:00', '03/01/19 09:00','03/01/19 09:00','03/01/19 09:00',
]
```

The desired dictionary would look like this:

```
dtd = {
    '03/01/19': {
         '00': 0, '01': 0, '02': 0, '03': 0, '04': 0, '05': 0,
         '06': 0, '07': 0, '08': 0, '09': 3, '10': 2, '11': 1,
         '12': 5, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 1,
         '18': 0, '19': 0, '20': 0, '21': 1, '22': 0, '23': 0,
     },
     '04/01/19': {
         '00': 0, ... '23': 0
     },
     '05/01/19': {
         '00': 0, ... 
     } ... etc
}
```

Clearly I can initialise a dictionary with at least the keys:

```
{i.split()[0]:{} for i in dtl}
```

But then I can't get my head round what I need to do to update the subdicts with the counts, & so can't see a way to get from the original list to the desired dictionary. I'm going round in circles!

Comment: Just to confirm all the times are on the hour? Won't see any `09:30`?

Comment: @hqkhan correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the use of `collections.defaultdict` since some of your counts can be 0.

Here's an option:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dtl = ['06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 11:00', 
       '05/01/19 21:00', '05/01/19 17:00', '05/01/19 17:00', 
       '05/01/19 14:00', '03/01/19 21:00', '03/01/19 17:00',
       '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', 
       '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 11:00', 
       '03/01/19 10:00', '03/01/19 10:00', '03/01/19 09:00',
       '03/01/19 09:00','03/01/19 09:00',]

# Nested defaultdict
result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for date_time in dtl:
    date, time = date_time.split()
    result[date][time.split(':')[0]] += 1
```

Output (using `pprint`):

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f20d5c37c80>,
            {'03/01/19': defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
                                     {'09': 3,
                                      '10': 2,
                                      '11': 1,
                                      '12': 5,
                                      '17': 1,
                                      '21': 1}),
             '05/01/19': defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
                                     {'14': 1,
                                      '17': 2,
                                      '21': 1}),
             '06/01/19': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'12': 2, '11': 1})})
```

If you really want to show the `0` for printing then I don't really see a way around keeping an array of `times` as I've done here and initializing your `dict` that way.

```
times = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
         '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21',
         '22', '23']

dtl = ['06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 11:00', 
       '05/01/19 21:00', '05/01/19 17:00', '05/01/19 17:00', 
       '05/01/19 14:00', '03/01/19 21:00', '03/01/19 17:00',
       '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', 
       '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 11:00', 
       '03/01/19 10:00', '03/01/19 10:00', '03/01/19 09:00',
       '03/01/19 09:00','03/01/19 09:00']

result = {date_time.split()[0] : {time : 0 for time in times} for date_time in dtl}

for date_time in dtl:
    date, time = date_time.split()
    result[date][time.split(':')[0]] += 1
```

Output below:

```
{'06/01/19': {'00': 0, '01': 0, '02': 0, '03': 0, '04': 0, '05': 0, '06': 0, '07': 0, '08': 0, '09': 0, '10': 0, '11': 1, '12': 2, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, '20': 0, '21': 0, '22': 0, '23': 0}, '05/01/19': {'00': 0, '01': 0, '02': 0, '03': 0, '04': 0, '05': 0, '06': 0, '07': 0, '08': 0, '09': 0, '10': 0, '11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 1, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 2, '18': 0, '19': 0, '20': 0, '21': 1, '22': 0, '23': 0}, '03/01/19': {'00': 0, '01': 0, '02': 0, '03': 0, '04': 0, '05': 0, '06': 0, '07': 0, '08': 0, '09': 3, '10': 2, '11': 1, '12': 5, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 1, '18': 0, '19': 0, '20': 0, '21': 1, '22': 0, '23': 0}}
```

Comment: Both this answer and that by @mad-physicist are to the point and extremely helpful, but this one has the edge for me as it provides for filling the 'empty' values in the final dict.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do this pretty effectively once you have split into a dictionary by date. So first split by date:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

dtd = defaultdict(list)
for date, time in (item.split() for item in dtl):
    dtd[date].append(time[:2])
```

Now you can easily count the existing items, and use them to initialize a `defaultdict` that will return zeros for the missing times:

```
for key in dtd:
    dtd[key] = defaultdict(int, Counter(dtd[key]))
```

The result is:

```
defaultdict(list, {
    '03/01/19': defaultdict(int, {
        '09': 3,
        '10': 2,
        '11': 1,
        '12': 5,
        '17': 1,
        '21': 1
    }),
    '05/01/19': defaultdict(int, {'14': 1, '17': 2, '21': 1}),
    '06/01/19': defaultdict(int, {'11': 1, '12': 2})
})
```

Since the objects here are `defaultdict`s, you will be able to query dates and times that were not in the original dataset. You can avoid this by converting the result to a regular `dict` containing only the keys you want after you finish:

```
hours = ['%02d' % h for h in range(24)]
dtd = {date: {h: d[h] for h in hours} for date, d in dtd}
```

Comment: Slightly confused by the remark "use them to initialize a defaultdict that will return zeros for the missing times:" as in the example output, the 'missing hours' aren't shown; But I may have misunderstood the intent.

Comment: @CodeRedacted So this has to do with the way `defaultdict` works. It will initialize your value to something if the `key` you tried wasn't in fact inside the `dict`. For instance if `test = {1: 20, 2: 25}`. Assuming `test` is a `defaultdict`, you tried issuing `test[15]`, even though `15` doesn't exist inside `test`, you will get back `0` and not a `KeyError`. The same behavior can be done using `.get(key, default_value)` I believe but `defaultdict` makes things look neat.

Comment: @hqkhan. The advantage of `defaultdict` over `get` or `setdefault` is that `defaultdict` only calls the constructor you pass in when the key is missing. With the `dict` methods, you call the constructor every time, before calling the method, resulting in usually harmless but unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Nice. Good to know.

Comment: @CodeRedacted. A defaultdict only shows the keys you set, but it allows you to query any key at all. `dtd['blah']` will return `[]`, while `dtd[03/01/19]['blah']` will return 0. Since it makes sense that you wouldn't want to have this happen for arbitrary times and dates, I've added a snippet to quickly convert to a normal nested dictionary to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def convert(dt):
    ret = {}
    for elem in dt:
        d,t = elem.split()
        t = t.split(":")[0]
        # not a valid value
        if not d: pass

        # we inserted d already
        if d in ret:
            if t in ret[d]:
                ret[d][t] += 1
        else:
            ret[d] = {'00': 0, '01': 0, '02': 0, '03': 0, '04': 0, '05': 0,
                    '06': 0, '07': 0, '08': 0, '09': 0, '10': 0, '11': 0, 
                    '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, 
                    '18': 0, '19': 0, '20': 0, '21': 0, '22': 0, '23': 0 }
    return ret

dtl = ['06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 12:00', '06/01/19 11:00', '05/01/19 21:00', '05/01/19 17:00', '05/01/19 17:00', '05/01/19 14:00', '03/01/19 21:00', '03/01/19 17:00','03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 12:00', '03/01/19 11:00', '03/01/19 10:00', '03/01/19 10:00', '03/01/19 09:00','03/01/19 09:00','03/01/19 09:00']

print(convert(dtl))
```

Comment: `ret[d] = {}`. Did you forget to insert the first time and add 1? Similarly, in the `if` portion, you should be starting with 1, not 0.

Comment: yup you are right, was not in the right format, too.